# What's the reading of kanji "入" in "入る", "hai" or "hairu"?

Tags: etymology, suffixes

If I look up the word "入る" in a dictionary, it would tell me its reading is はい・る, but does that mean the kanji "入" is read as はい? If I look up the kanji in 漢字源, It's obviously wrong. The kanji "入" is read as はいる.

[image: Here is the what I found under the entry "入" in 漢字源]

And from my understanding, the only reason we have to add an okurigana to the kanji is to help us distinguish this "入" from other "入"s. If I am right, then how to make sense of "入ら"?

If we are talking about inflection, then 入る can be understood as base "入" + suffix "る", hence 入ら can be understood as "入" + "ら"; but the thing that bothers me the most is the fact that "はい" is not the equivalent of the kanji "入". So is it better for me to treat "入る" and "入ら" as separate words? Is there a better understanding?

Comment: What does 漢字源 say?

Comment: @aguijonazo I edited the post and supplemented a screenshot of the dictionary.

Comment: Oh, that's misleading. It should be written as はい...る as in the 常用音訓 section above.

Answer (score 4):

一般的には、送り仮名をわかりやすくするために**入**（その漢字の読み方） + **る**（送り仮名）と辞書に書くことが多いです。　送り仮名の表記方法として「・」が使われます。
今回の例ですと、入（漢）・る（送）です。